# how to avoid lookbehind assertion is not fixed length

Tags: grep

I have a file that contains a version number that I need to output. This version number is apart of a string in this file, that looks something like this:

```
https://some-link:1234/path/to/file/name-of-file/1.2.345/name-of-file_CXP123456-1.2.345.jar"
```

I need to get the version number, which is 1.2.345.

This grep command works: `grep -Po '(?<=/name-of-file_CXP123456-/)\d.\d.\d\d\d'`. **However, the CXP number changes** and as such I thought I could do something like this: `grep -Po '(?<=/name-of-file_*-/)\d.\d.\d\d\d'` but that gives the following:

`grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

Is there anything I can add to the grep statement to avoid this?

Ultimately, this is part of a stage in Jenkins to get this version number. The sh command looks something like this:

```
VERSION = sh 'ssh -tt user@ip-address "cat dir/file*.content | grep -Po '(?<=/name-of-file_*-/)\d.\d.\d\d\d' 1>&2"'
```

Comment: You can't nest the single quotes used to quote `grep`'s argument inside the single quotes used to quote the entire shell pipeline.

Comment: this part `_*` matches optional underscores. If you can use `-Po` you can look into using `\K` forgetting what is matched so far, as an alternative to the lookbehind. So you can first match, and then use `\K` like this for example `/name-of-file_CXP123456-\K\d.\d.\d\d\d`

Comment: bash built-in regexps don't support lookbehind at all. `grep -P` is a completely separate regex implementation that has nothing whatsoever to do with bash itself.

Comment: Moreover, your code specifies `sh`, which is _pointedly_ not bash. (Even when `sh` _is_ provided by bash, it runs in a compatibility mode disabling some features when invoked under that name).

Comment: @Thefourthbird I don't think that works as when I do the following: `grep -Po 'filename_CXP123453-\K\d.\d.\d\d\d'` (where the CXP number is different to what it is actually), nothing gets outputted

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```sh
grep -Po '/name-of-file_.*-\K\d+(?:\.\d+)+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0XIsLK/1). *Details*:

- `/name-of-file_` - a literal text
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\K` - a match reset operator that omits all text matched so far from the memory buffer
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)+` - one or more sequences of a `.` and one or more digits.

Comment: This works if I provide the exact file name which (at this moment in time), has a certain CXP number. However, this CXP number will change. So it could file_CXP1234 now but it could file_CXP5678 at another point in time. I'm not sure how to handle this as editing your solution to use a wildcard (file_CXP*) doesn't output anything

Comment: @KevinNiland Show me a regex demo. The solution above works well for the strings that follow the pattern I described and that matches the string you shared in the question. Make sure you provide the real-life strings in the question, or describe the strings you have in every detail so that our answers could be generalized more for all your inputs.

Comment: @KevinNiland Do you mean you want `/name-of-file_CXP\d+-\K\d+(?:\.\d+)+`? See https://regex101.com/r/0XIsLK/2

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lookbehind for this job. You also don't need PCREs, or `grep` at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- bash, *not* sh
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "ERROR: bash required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

string="https://some-link:1234/path/to/file/name-of-file/1.2.345/name-of-file_CXP123456-1.2.345.jar"
regex='.*/name-of-file_CXP[[:digit:]]+-([[:digit:].]+)[.]jar'

if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "Version is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  echo "No version found in $string"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too long for a comment... It looks like the version number is the 2nd-to last field if you split on forward slash?

- `rev | cut -d/ -f 2 | rev`
- `awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'`
- `perl -lanF/ -e 'print $F[-2]'`

Or even something like: `basename $(dirname $(cat filename))`

Answer (score 0):

For those that are really desperate, there is another solution which requires you to pre-build your regex string.
It's not a solution I would recommend, but if there is really no other way, no one can stop you.

While even with this you won't have true dynamic look-behinds and it is still quite limited, it is an option available to you.

The idea is to build the look-behind for each possible length you need it to be.
So for example only match if it's not preceded by a `#` (0 to a 100 characters look-behind).

```bash
reg='';
for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++)); do reg+='(?<!#.{'"${i}"'})'; done;
reg+='someVariableName=.*?($|;|\\n)';
grep --perl-regexp "$reg" /home/username/some.cfg
```

This might not be the best example, but it gets the idea across.
This solution has its own pitfalls. For example, you need to double escape `\\` escape-sequences like `\n` and any character that should not be interpreted should be put in a single-quote string (or use `printf`).

Answer (score 0):

Another simple, portable solution:

```
sed -n 's%.*_CXP[[:digit:]]*-\([.[:digit:]]*\)\.jar$%\1%p' <<<https://some-link:1234/path/to/file/name-of-file/1.2.345/name-of-file_CXP123456-1.2.345.jar
```

The `<<<` here string is a Bash extension; for `sh` and friends, you can replace that with a here document.

```
sed -n 's%.*_CXP[[:digit:]]*-\([.[:digit:]]*\)\.jar$%\1%p' <<'____HERE'
https://some-link:1234/path/to/file/name-of-file/1.2.345/name-of-file_CXP123456-1.2.345.jar
____HERE
```

I was lazy so my capturing regex is more relaxed than yours; obviously, if you know exactly how many digits or dots to expect, you can tighten it up if you need to. Notice, though, that `sed` does not portably support the Perl extension `\d` (or its friends `\w`, `\s`, etc).